# How to press a button, move to the next position of an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'm starting to program in android and I'm a difficulty. I'm filling an ArrayList seeking a database object.

```
 public ArrayList<Box> seekBoxPerLine() {
        boxes = new ArrayList<Box>();
        Cursor cursor;
        if (init == 0) {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Boxe WHERE line='" + numberLine+ "' ORDER BY position ASC; ";
            cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
        } else {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Box WHERE line='" + numberLine + "' ORDER BY positio DESC; ";
            cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
        }
        if (cursor.getCount() >= 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Box box = new Box();

                box.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
                box.setFase_cultivo(cursor.getString(1));
                boxes.add(box);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return boxes;
    }
```

I do a verification, and pass the id of my object to a EditText:

```
  public void verifyBoxLine() {
        if (numberLine != null) {
            boxes = seekBoxPerLine();
            for (Box boxesPerLine : boxes) {
                etNumberBoxActually.setText(String.valueOf(boxesPerLine.getId()));

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my doubt is how to program the button to press it to him increment the same EditText with the next arrayList ID? I have no idea any help is welcome.

My onClick button:

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
 if (view == btNextBox) {


        }
```

notes: The boxes are positioned in a line sequentially and I can choose to start at the beginning or the end of the line, so i realize the checks, do not know how much it helps but it would be to make it clearer.

Comment: honestly it's quite hard to understand the code if you don't speak portoguese(?)....

Comment: sorry i go switch to English for clarity

Comment: see now became clearer

Comment: thank you very very much, sorry, i didn't want to be mean!

Comment: without problems, my mistake not to think about it too

Comment: i'm really glad i could help you out - this stuff happens to me also very often =) i'm always glad to help and always glad to get help ^_^ i hope we see anytime again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use an internal counter?

whenever you query from the DB you reset the counter to 0;

whenever you click on the button, you increase the counter...

```
private int indexPos = 0;

public ArrayList<Box> seekBoxPerLine() {
    //... as above
    indexPos = 0;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btNextBox) {
        indexPos = indexPos + 1;
        //... do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, but how can I seek the position of the counter within the array? Sorry I'm a little bad with lists array = /

Comment: 'public void onClick(View view) { 
          if (view == btNextBox) { 
              for (int i=0; i<tanques.size(); i++) { 
                  if (i == count) { 
                       etNumberBoxActually.setText(String.valueOf(boxes));                             buscaInformacaoArracoamento(); indexPos += 1; } } }'

but how can I get the Box ID within the Array?

Comment: Hey man i'm very very thank you for your so simple solution solved my problem. thank you so much